# oscMax jquery nested tabs issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, oscommerce

5.5 install where in the admin/categories.php file if you click on the Short Description Tab in the product editor it refreshes the page and then displays the entire page within that tab

Inspecting the element in crome sees the page continuing to try and load and reload

logging reports the following errors:

```
(Forbidden)
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'css' of undefined
GET /catalog/management/categories.php?cPath=…/catalog/management/categories.php?cPath=1_409&pID=1890&action=new_product 414 (Request-URI Too Long)
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectedIndex' of undefined
GET /catalog/images/thumbs/ 403 (Forbidden)
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'css' of undefined
GET /catalog/management/categories.php?cPath=…/catalog/management/categories.php?cPath=1_409&pID=1890&action=new_product 414 (Request-URI Too Long)

I cannot see why this is occurring.

Anyone have any suggestions on how i can debug and resolve this?

TIA